# quantum eraser question

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a question concerning the quantum eraser: Let's assume you have two envelopes with one having the printed detector data and the other one having the printed measurement screen data, for a multitude of numbered double slit experiments. Now you separate the detector data and the measurement screen data and put the latter on a scale. When we assume that the printed image of an interference takes up more ink to print than the image of a double slit, the weight on the scale should increase in the moment the envelopes containing the detector data are destroyed. Is that what would happen? Does anyone know?

Edit:
I see, thanks for pointing that out. Here is the same thing more precise: You have a double slit set up and shoot a couple of single electrons through the slits recording which slit each electron takes. You also record the measurement screen data. You do that for several electrons all in the same way and after the experiment you print out all your data. If you look at the screen data you will see two slits, when you still have the possibility to look at the detector data. If you destroy the detector data before you look at the screen data, you will see interference. The printed image of a interference weighs more than the printed image of a double slit, because it has more ink on it (assumption). Now, before you open and look at any data, you put all screen data on a scale and look at the weight. Then, when you destroy the detector data, your screen data will change from double slit to interference, meaning it has more ink on it, so it increases in weight. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Sorry, I could not follow your reasoning, and I guess, others will have the same problem. Please clarify the starting point of your reasoning, the assumptions that go into it, and make it transparent, why you arrive at your conclusion. I also miss a clear content-oriented question.

Answer (score 3):

> If you destroy the detector data before you look at the screen data, you will see interference.

No, that's not how the quantum-eraser experiment works.

If you have a two-slit interference configuration, and the which-way information is available *even in principle*, then no interference will appear on the screen. Whether this information is recorded in ways that a human can make sense of (or in that we can't, say, in some subtle, complicated change in the distribution of ink molecules inside an ash pile) is utterly irrelevant. If there are physical systems that have their state altered by the which-way information, then the interference pattern goes away.

The quantum-eraser protocol does produce a way to completely erase that which-way information, by performing a specific measurement onto a superposition pair of states, on *all* the systems that have had their state altered by the which-way information, and then post-selecting data out of the screen depending on what was the superposition-measurement outcome.

"Destroying the detector data" does nothing to restore the interference pattern. If the text you're reading actively states such a thing, that's a single-strike-and-you're-out for that text - discard it, and get a better book.

Comment: So, you're saying burning the which-way information doesn't change anything? In this video at 5:44 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo176uIPmbY it states that it will change the screen data. Or am I getting it wrong? I am new to this...

Comment: That video is utterly wrong. Disregard it and find a better source.