# If the experimentalist does not look at the recorded data in the 'which-way' experiment, will it affect the inference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-measurements

Related question [quantum eraser question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461767/quantum-eraser-question/461775#461775)

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#%22Which-way%22_experiments_and_the_principle_of_complementarity

> "Which-way" experiments and the principle of complementarity
> A well-known thought experiment predicts that if particle detectors are positioned at the slits, showing through which slit a photon goes, the interference pattern will disappear.[6]

My questions are:

(1) if the experimentalist does not look at the data of the detector, despite the detector looks like working, will the interference still disappear at the screen?

(2) if the answer to the question (1) is, still disappear, then what would be the definition(s) of measurement/observer? Because in step (1), the experimentalist will not know the result of measuring the electron goes to which slot, the measurement will proceed up to the device, not the experimentalist (if observer is the human, then it seems lead to subtly).

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to put detectors on the slits to measure which way was taken. The interference pattern will dissapear. You don't need a human being to notice the results. The point is interaction (an event happening somewhere on slit A or B, not that someone notices it). Things happen without someone spending attention to it all the time.

Comment: I thought about it and would agree. If there is any literature on this point (if not too stupid to mention), that would be helpful.

Comment: @AlphaF20 Maybe you can use this as a starting point <https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)> (second paragraph) for further reading.

Comment: I'll second @AlphaF20 's request for literature. Considering how often this comes up, it would be nice to have a source handy for an experimental paper where it was explicitly checked that not reading the detector as a human still destroyed the interference.

Comment: @doublefelix In the Wikipedia article are 3 references (4 to 6), but these are more statements of Heisenberg, Feynman etc. Not sure if someone really did an experiment leaving on detectors behind the slits, leaving the lab and checking after one hour if an interference pattern appeared.